# Adding Array to MySQL Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, fetch

I'm fetching results from my database (fetchAll), and later encoding it into json.

However, I want to add additional values to it, but I have no idea how to achieve that.

I tried doing this is:

```
while ($posts = $database->fetchAll()) {
    $posts['additional'] = 'test';
}
```

But it wasn't working.

The result I'm after is changing the results from this:

```
[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

to

```
[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "additional":"test"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "additional":"test"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "additional":"test"}
]
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to add additional data to the currently fetched results (in array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `fetchAll` and `while` together.

Then:

```
$posts = array();
while ($post = $database->fetch()) {
    $post['additional'] = 'test';
    $posts[] = $post;
}
```

Or:

```
$posts = $database->fetchAll();
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
  $post['additional'] = 'test';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works fine your way. :)